# Position bootstrap popover

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to implement a popover for language selection, but encounter two problems:

1) The popover is hidden above the footer when I apply `position: absolute;` to the footer.

2) The popover sticks to the right side of my page. I would like a margin there, but `margin-right` doesn't seem to have effect.

[Here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eyzn390s/).

Note: this might not be the case with newer versions of bootstrap, but I'm using this one in the rest of my site and migration to a newer version is out of scope for now...

EDIT: I fixed the first problem by adding `{container: 'body'}` [to the tooltip](http://jsfiddle.net/eyzn390s/1/). Second one still open...

EDIT 2: I managed to add a [margin on the right](http://jsfiddle.net/eyzn390s/2/) by using:

```
.popover
{
  right: 10px !important;
  left: auto !important;
}
```

The only problem now is that the arrow isn't centered with the text beneath the arrow anymore... any tips?

Comment: Please publish your code also here

Comment: The full code is in the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is by adding a fixed position `position:fixed; right:40px;` to your `#wrapper`. This will allow you to adjust your  position to the left and or right. However, if you attempt to adjust top or bottom it will break out of its parent container and be relative to the document. Therefore, if you need to make adjustments to top or bottom use margins.

```
#wrapper{
  min-height: 50px;
  max-height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position:fixed;
  right:40px;
}
```